# Combining 2 patch files

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch

I'm new to Git, and I am trying to contribute to an open source repo using patch files.

I created a patch for one class, then later on I needed to modify something else in the same class, so I went ahead and make another patch for it.

Now I've got two patches for 1 class, and would like to combine them, but I am new, and after I read as many stackoverflows of this same question, I still don't understand how exactly I would go upon doing this.

I heard that rebase has some way of doing, but I think that might mess something up, not sure exactly how to do this.

Sorry for posting something so similar to other questions, I need this cleared up. Also, I don't quite understand what rebase actually does, but anything that has to do with messing with branches sounds dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already apply both patches then:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

In the editor, either squash of fixup the last commit, and save.

Comment: Okay, so I saved my other patch to a separate file, committed, and pushed. Now I have 2 patch files, but when I run that command, I get: Cannot 'squash' without a previous commit